# How to make tuple of differing const-ness?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a function that returns several objects inside a tuple.

Edit: Specifically trying to do something like this if this makes sense...

```cpp
std::tuple<const std::vector<float>, class1, const class2> data = foo();
```

where foo returns something like:

```cpp
return std::make_tuple(vec, instance1, instance2);
```

I want **instance1** to be the only modifiable value in the tuple after it gets returned and initialized. I want to reduce the amount of copying I do returning from this function at the same time because the vector contains a lot of floats. I want to know the most efficient way to return my tuple with the least amount of copying.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine.  You can make some elements in a tuple `const`.

In fact, this is what `map` does with `pair`: its key-value pair is of type `std::pair<const key_type, value_type>` to prevent modification to the key.

Comment: The returning const elements part is okay? Just clarifying.

Comment: @Fillups Why do you want to return const?  We don't usually do `const int f();` because we've made a copy anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to make the **vec** and **class2** un-modifiable. I know I can make the return handler ```const```, and that return by value const is pointless because the copy placed in the handler is dependent on its own qualifiers, and not those from the return value. From your comment, I guess containers copy the same way? So it's pointless to return a ```const``` container, and RVO doesn't change how ```const``` works, correct? Because it just copies the small stack value that points to container data allocated on the heap? Am I getting warmer?

Comment: @Fillups `vec` and `class2` are copied (not moved) into the tuple, so they can't get modified from the returned tuple.

Comment: I make the vector in the function, and I really want to move that because it has a lot of data and would be really expensive to copy after I make it. ```class1``` and ```class2``` I don't mind copying because they are so small, and it should be a one time deal to pack it in the tuple. After I move and copy to the tuple, I'm trying to return the tuple efficiently and lock out modification to ```vec``` and ```class2```. After it's in the tuple and modification is restricted appropriately, I'm in the clear to just pass it by reference. I'm trying to take advantage of RVO for STL containers.

Comment: @Fillups Can you update your question with a [mre] to provide context?  Because I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I updated the question a little bit to get rid of returning constant objects. Hopefully this makes more sense. I'm not yet sure what to ask to make my question clear.

Comment: @Fillups: Making the `vector` `const` on the caller side doesn't save you anything; you're returning by value, and `std::make_tuple` already made the copy for you; preventing mutation after doesn't help. If `vec` is being expensively generated on each call and you want to avoid the copy, why not just do `return std::make_tuple(std::move(vec), instance1, instance2)`, so your (about to be destroyed) local `vector` is cheaply transferred to the caller with just few register width copies, regardless of size? Caller receives mutable results, but they got them cheaply, no extra copies.

Comment: @ShadowRanger One of the things I'm trying to do is prevent mutation afterwards. I want those particular elements to be immutable after the tuple is created because those particular elements ```vec``` and ```instance 2``` need to remain un-modifiable after their creation for safety purposes, and those two elements are used by subsequent functions receiving this tuple as an reference argument. I just wanted to optimize how ```data``` receives the return value.